# Does Gauss' Law apply to real physical solid conductors?

Tags: electrostatics, gauss-law

In a conductor there is no electric field because there is no charge. There is no charge inside because any charges present inside would repel each other and be driven to the surface of the conductor.

However, suppose I have a sphere with no net charge, and I take a tiny Gaussian surface and place it around a proton of any atom in the middle of the conductor, by Gauss' Law there **should** be an electric field. So, perhaps Gauss' Law only applies to conductors where the charge is perfectly uniform throughout, i.e. to "ideal" conductors and not to real ones?

Comment: There are plenty of charges inside real conductors. A metal is a positively charged lattice and an electron sea. There are very large local fields on the atomic level, and as soon as a current flows trough a metal, there is a macroscopic electric field. Electrodynamics applies to all of that. As soon as we get to the atomic level, of course, we have to treat atoms and electrons as quantum objects, otherwise one can't even explain the existence of the crystal lattice and its metallic properties. To the best of my knowledge all of that can be done with a classical description of electrodynamics.

Comment: @CuriousOne so then Gauss is assuming an ideal case?

Comment: Not an ideal case but a special case where the electric field is caused by static charges which do not exist in real conductors in the simple way that we postulate them in an idealized version of electrostatics. To understand what's going in inside a real conductor requires quantum mechanics, thermodynamics and, at the very least, a rudimentary understanding of black body radiation, because the conductor is in thermal equilibrium with the vacuum.